# How to get argmax/argmin of multiple fields simultaneously in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

Here's the data example I'm working with.

```py
[
  {
    "uid": "111",
    "a": 1,
    "b": 3,
    "c": 1,
    
  },
  {
    "uid": "222",
    "a": 2,
    "b": 2,
    "c": 2
  },
  {
    "uid": "333",
    "a": 3,
    "b": 1,
    "c": 3
  }
]
```

Then I want to perform `argmax` on fields "a" and "b", and `argmin` on field "c" and return the `"uid"` as the result.

For example:

For "a", it's maximum value is 3, the corresponding "uid" is "333", so `argmax` of "a" should be `"uid" : "333"`.

The question is what query should be executed so that I can get the result as below?

```py
[
  {
    "argmax_of_a": "333",
    "argmax_of_b": "111",
    "argmin_of_c": "111",
  }
]
```

Here's the code snipped I'm playing with https://mongoplayground.net/p/gEDuHd-aCiZ

I can find someway to get `argmax/argmin` of one specific field, but I have no idea how to work on multiple fields simultaneously.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose it always returns the first matching result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give this aggreation pipeline a try:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            a: { $push: { uid: '$uid', val: '$a' } },
            b: { $push: { uid: '$uid', val: '$b' } },
            c: { $push: { uid: '$uid', val: '$c' } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            max_of_a: { $arrayElemAt: ["$a", { $indexOfArray: ["$a.val", { $max: '$a.val' }] }] },
            max_of_b: { $arrayElemAt: ["$b", { $indexOfArray: ["$b.val", { $max: '$b.val' }] }] },
            max_of_c: { $arrayElemAt: ["$c", { $indexOfArray: ["$c.val", { $max: '$c.val' }] }] }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            arg_max_of_a: '$max_of_a.uid',
            arg_max_of_b: '$max_of_b.uid',
            arg_max_of_c: '$max_of_c.uid'
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Amazing solution! Thank you. 
But I'm not sure about the performance of this query? Like comparing with the sort one.

Comment: it should work ok for a few thousand documents. i'll give it a another whirl when i have some time to come up with a more performant way.